# Nested Parallel loop gives index was outside the bound while adding value to a list

Tags: c#, list, nested-loops, parallel.foreach

I have a List-A to populate List-B with more value that comes from database and populates another List-C. I'm using parallel loop and normal foreach loop. If I use just foreach loop, it takes about 19 minutes to populate List-C, but using parallel loop it only takes 3 minutes to populate same list.

But for some reason, when adding List-B to List C, it gives out an error
"Index was outside the bounds of the array", with no informations

```
List<Variance> Variances = new List<Variance>();
Parallel.ForEach(words, (word) =>
{
     List<wordConfig> configlist = new List<wordConfig>();
     foreach (VariancePopulationConfig value in values)
     {
         VariancePopulationConfig config = new VariancePopulationConfig(Named, Category, Schedule);

         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
         {
             con.Open();
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
             cmd.Connection = con;
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", word);
             cmd.Connection = con;
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
             cmd.CommandText = value.SelectQuery;
             returnedvalue = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
             config.DestinationColOrdinal = value.DestinationColOrdinal;
             config.CurrentOrHistory = value.CurrentOrHistory;
             config.WordValue = returnedvalue.Equals("0") ? string.Empty : returnedvalue;
             config.Word = word;
         }
         configlist.Add(config);
     }
     Variances.Add(new Variance { Word = word, VarianceConfigs = configlist });
});
```

Comment: `Variances.Add` is not thread safe inside parallel foreach. consider using lock statement or concurrent collections like concurrent bag

Comment: Seems to be working now, thanks @dasblinkenlight

Comment: No more error, but some values are populating at random places for some of the items.

Answer (score 2):

You get an out-of-bound error because you are adding items to a growing list from multiple threads. One thread tries to expand the array, while the other is accessing the old one.

You can fix this problem by replacing `Parallel.ForEach` with `AsParallel` and `Select`, like this:

```
var Variances = words.AsParallel().Select((word) => {
     List<wordConfig> configlist = new List<wordConfig>();
     foreach (VariancePopulationConfig value in values) {
         VariancePopulationConfig config = new VariancePopulationConfig(Named, Category, Schedule);
         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
             con.Open();
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
             cmd.Connection = con;
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", word);
             cmd.Connection = con;
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
             cmd.CommandText = value.SelectQuery;
             returnedvalue = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
             config.DestinationColOrdinal = value.DestinationColOrdinal;
             config.CurrentOrHistory = value.CurrentOrHistory;
             config.WordValue = returnedvalue.Equals("0") ? string.Empty : returnedvalue;
             config.Word = word;
         }
         configlist.Add(config);
     }
     return new Variance { Word = word, VarianceConfigs = configlist };
}).ToList();
```

> No more error, but some values are populating at random places for some of the items.

By default parallel select [does not preserve original ordering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677(v=vs.110).aspx). You can fix this by adding `.AsOrdered()` after `AsParallel()`, but there is a chance that the performance would degrade.